# Disable auto fullscreen of YouTube embeds on iPhone

Tags: ios, youtube, webkit, html5-video, mobile-safari

As we will know from other questions on the site to in iOS Mobile Safari we have these tasty attributes `webkit-playesinline` and the more concise `playsinline` to disable auto fullscreen of videos.

Despite that miracle I'm still unable to figure out how to add this to YouTube html5 embeds. As expected the YouTube `<video>` is contained within an `<iframe>`.

the ideal result is something as the following:

```
<video 
    tabindex="-1" 
    class="video-stream html5-main-video" 
    style="width: 736px; height: 414px; left: 85px; top: 0px;" 
    src="blob:https://www.youtube.com/6889sdad6d2-ec51-49ca-b357-a5bd9c3ede71" 
    webkit-playsinline="true" 
    playsinline="true">
</video>
```

I have tried, in vain, to do this via jquery.

Any thoughts or ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Add `playsinline=1` paramerer to the embed url. Add `?` or `&` before as appropriate; `?` if the only paramerter, `&` to concatenate with other params.

Example:

```
<iframe
  src="https://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?playsinline=1">
</iframe>
```

From [YouTube iFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters):

> This parameter controls whether videos play inline or fullscreen in an HTML5 player on iOS. Valid values are:
>   0: This value causes fullscreen playback. This is currently the default value, though the default is subject to change.
>   1: This value causes inline playback for UIWebViews created with the allowsInlineMediaPlayback property set to TRUE.

Comment: As a note if you're using the javascript load style, it's like `playerVars: {'controls': 0, 'playsinline': 1 },`

Comment: @rogerdpack For the record, were you able to autoplay youtube-player-API-inserted videos in a browser in iOS? Mine aren't consistent: sometimes they do, sometimes they don't (React).

Comment: long, rough day ... just the solution I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @JohnContarino the day i came across this this was also a long day. glad it could help!

Comment: why i can't get this to work ? i'm using ionic mu url is something like this https://www.youtube.com/embed/idididdididi?playsinline=1

Comment: not sure about the interaction when you are using an ionic app~ you may need to use a native library. I also seem to remeber some issues if `/embed/` is in the url

Answer (score -1):

As per the current API description, playsinline should be set to 0 to avoid fullscreen on iOS devices.

See below description, found on: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

[image: See below description, found on: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters]